# Windows Phone 7.1 emulator does not load application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, emulation

I'm currently working on my first application targeting Windows Phone 7.1 and can't seem to get it running in the emulator. The project builds successfully, but when I debug the emulator screen stays black. No exceptions seem to be thrown and I can get the program to break on breakpoints, though no variables appear in the Locals window. I've tried each of the available emulators with no luck:

- Windows Phone Emulator - 512 MB
- Windows Phone Emulator - 256 MB
- Windows Phone Emulator 7.8 512 MB
- Windows Phone Emulator 7.8 256 MB

Another post on the Interwebz said to make sure the Build and Deploy boxes are both checked in the Configuration Manager, and mine are.

My MainPage.xaml isn't anything crazy:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="NationalParkGuide.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/MainViewModelSampleData.xaml}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait"  Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <!--Panorama control-->
        <controls:Panorama Title="national park guide">
            <controls:Panorama.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Yosemite.jpg" />
            </controls:Panorama.Background>

            <!--Panorama item one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="menu">
                <!--Double line list with text wrapping-->
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="78">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>

            <!--Panorama item two-->
            <!--Use 'Orientation="Horizontal"' to enable a panel that lays out horizontally-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="second item">
                <!--Double line list with image placeholder and text wrapping-->
                <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
                                <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFE5001b" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
                                <StackPanel Width="311">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineOne}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </controls:PanoramaItem>
        </controls:Panorama>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs hasn't been modified from auto-generated code yet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace NationalParkGuide
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = App.ViewModel;
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
            {
                App.ViewModel.LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Help! :)

**Additional Information**

I ran dxdiag.exe and can confirm I meet the requirements for the 7.1 emulator. DirectX 11 and WDDM 1.1.

Comment: Please describe what happens when you try to run emulator. There is a chance that application just crashes. Try to do a debug (F5) in Visual Studio and see how far it goes.

Comment: I've updated the post to describe what happens in debug.

Comment: I have ran your code and its working fine.. according to me there is nothing wrong in this code. there must be some problem in Your system requirements to run this program.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have already 3 apps deployed on the emulator